# Convert time to seconds format in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a data frame with 2 column `Date` and `time` with type in string.

```
      Date      Time
20/11/2017  22:49:05
20/11/2017  22:51:07
20/11/2017  22:53:07
20/11/2017  22:58:07
```

I want to convert these two column into one column which is in seconds compare to 1970/01/01.

Anyone knows how to do that without install any packages but `time` `numpy` `pandas` packages? Because I can not install package on my server which I don't have permission to do that, and the above three packages are pre-installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Use string or regular expression library to parse each row into structured time data. Use `time.mktime()' to convert the structured time to second after 1970. See example here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_mktime.htm

Comment: I want to conver it to UNIX format, sorry I forgot what it called before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the integer representation of a `datetime` series:

```
# convert to datetime
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time'))

# extract seconds
df['unix_seconds'] = df['DateTime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

print(df)

             DateTime  unix_seconds
0 2017-11-20 22:49:05    1511218145
1 2017-11-20 22:51:07    1511218267
2 2017-11-20 22:53:07    1511218387
3 2017-11-20 22:58:07    1511218687
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
df["datetime_column"] = (df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]).to_datetime(infer_datetime_format=True)
```

(or you could specify the actual format if you aren't lazy like me)

```
df["seconds"] = df["datetime_column"].dt.strftime("%s").astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.